# Timeout cassandra hector

Tags: cassandra, hector

i've started working with cassandra. Therefore I’ve download cassandra (1.1.1) to my windows pc and started it. Everything works fine. 
Thus I began to reimplement a old application (in java using hector 1.1) which imports about 200.000.000 for 4 tables, which should insertet into 4 columnfamilies. After importing about 2.000.000 records I get an timeout exception and cassandra doesn't response on requests:

```
2012-07-03 15:35:43,299 WARN  - Could not fullfill request on this host CassandraClient<localhost:9160-16>
2012-07-03 15:35:43,300 WARN  - Exception: me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HTimedOutException: TimedOutException()
....
Caused by: TimedOutException()
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$batch_mutate_result.read(Cassandra.java:20269)
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:922)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:908)
at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.MutatorImpl$3.execute(MutatorImpl.java:246)
at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.MutatorImpl$3.execute(MutatorImpl.java:243)
at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.Operation.executeAndSetResult(Operation.java:103)
at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.operateWithFailover(HConnectionManager.java:258)
```

The last entries inside the logfile are:

```
INFO 15:35:31,678 Writing Memtable-cf2@678837311(7447722/53551072 serialized/live bytes, 262236 ops)
INFO 15:35:32,810 Completed flushing \var\lib\cassandra\data\keySpaceName\cf2\keySpaceName-cf2-hd-205-Data.db (3292685 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=109596147695328, position=131717208)
INFO 15:35:33,282 Compacted to [\var\lib\cassandra\data\keySpaceName\cf3\keySpaceName-cf3-hd-29-Data.db,].  33.992.615 to 30.224.481 (~88% of original) bytes for 282.032 keys at 1,378099MB/s.  Time: 20.916ms.
INFO 15:35:33,286 Compacting [SSTableReader(path='\var\lib\cassandra\data\keySpaceName\cf4\keySpaceName-cf4-hd-8-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='\var\lib\cassandra\data\keySpaceName\cf4\keySpaceName-cf4-hd-6-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='\var\lib\cassandra\data\keySpaceName\cf4\keySpaceName-cf4-hd-7-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='\var\lib\cassandra\data\keySpaceName\cf4\keySpaceName-cf4-hd-5-Data.db')]
INFO 15:35:34,871 Compacted to [\var\lib\cassandra\data\keySpaceName\cf4\keySpaceName-cf4-hd-9-Data.db,].  4.249.270 to 2.471.543 (~58% of original) bytes for 30.270 keys at 1,489916MB/s.  Time: 1.582ms.
INFO 15:35:41,858 Compacted to [\var\lib\cassandra\data\keySpaceName\cf2\keySpaceName-cf2-hd-204-Data.db,].  48.868.818 to 24.033.164 (~49% of original) bytes for 135.367 keys at 2,019011MB/s.  Time: 11.352ms.
```

I created 4 column families like following:

```
ColumnFamilyDefinition cf1 = HFactory.createColumnFamilyDefinition(
“keyspacename”,
“cf1”,
ComparatorType.ASCIITYPE);
```

The column families have following column count:

1. 16 columns
2. 14 columns
3. 7 colmuns
4. 5 columns

The keyspace is created with replication factor 1 and default strategy (simple)
I insert the records (rows) with 'Mutator#AddInsertion'

Any advice avoiding this exception?

Regards 
WM

Comment: That's a lot of data to be inserting on a single node on your desktop.  Looks like you're being hurt by the compaction process.  If you run this in a real cluster (i.e. 3+ machines with RF=2) I doubt you'll see this issue.

Comment: I created a new enviroment as described below. Same issue

Comment: Can you post the code that does the inserts?

Comment: I have also facing the timeout exception while retrieving data from Cassandra database

Answer (score 1):

That exception is basically Cassandra saying that it's far enough behind on mutations that it won't complete your requests before they time out.  Assuming your PC isn't a beast, you should probably throttle your requests.  I suggest sleeping for a while after catching that exception and then retrying; there's no harm in accidentally writing the same row twice, and Cassandra should catch up on write pretty quickly.

If you were in a production environment, I would look more closely at other reasons why the node might be performing poorly.

Comment: My PC A has 4 cores, 8GB Ram. I added 2 PCs B and C (each 2 core, 4 GB ram) to the cluster and change replication factor to 2. A restart of the import has the same result. After the exception occurred I waited 10 minutes and open the cassandra command line. The execution of "describe cluster" results that the maschine A is unreachable.

Comment: I created a new environment. 3 PCs á 4 cores and 8 GB Ram. My program runs on an another PC. Inside the programm I catches the exception and added a delay and retry the insertion.

Comment: It sounds like the Cassandra process is either running out of heap space or the OS is killing it to free memory.  I'm not a Windows guy, so I don't know how to check for the second case, but you should see something in the logs if it is running out of heap space.

Comment: I got it. I changed the server log-level to DEBUG and got an exception `org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Cannot read. Remote side has closed. Tried to read 4 bytes, but only got 0 bytes.`. After running cassandra on a linux everything works (except an outofmemory-exception) works fine.